# debug1: No more authentication methods to try. Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)

Tags: linux, ssh, permissions, putty, scp

I use putty to connect to AWS EC2 server. Want to copy code from bastion server to publication server. However, when I tried to copy file using scp command, error occurs:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-16-1-185 uat]$ scp -rv source_uat/* ec2-user@172.10.101.150:/home/ec2-user/olegram
Executing: program /usr/bin/ssh host 172.10.101.155, user ec2-user, command scp -v -r -d -t /home/ec2-user/olegram
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Connecting to 172.10.101.155 [172.10.101.155] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 172.10.101.155:22 as 'ec2-user'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256 need=64 dh_need=64
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256 need=64 dh_need=64
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:jq4vyoFHyiheUJ9jeBl6fAgeuevl9oboMcsmfmHKo9g
debug1: Host '172.10.101.155' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/ec2-user/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
lost connection
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the authentication seems to have failed.

Did you miss any of those important steps?

1-Create a public-key / private-key pair

2-Inform the server of your public key

3-Tell putty where to find your private key

The user guide on the AWS website has a tutorial on how to do that;

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html

Comment: Yes, I have done these steps, I am not sure why the authentication  failed

Comment: The debug output says that putty tried using your private key (called id_dsa) and that the server refused it. There's only two options: the server did not authorize your public key, OR putty is using the wrong private key (it is unlikely, you should almost never have more than one private key on you computer).

Comment: why the server did not authorize the public key? Other guy have used the same method to login successfully

Comment: Usually the server authorizes the public key for a regular user (not for root). My guess is that you are trying to connect as the root user, while the public key belongs to a different user.

Comment: But I also tried ec2-user, also failed

Comment: So you are 100% sure that ec2-user is the user that received your public-key. And you are 100% that you are using the right private key. Can you edit your post to show the debug output when you connect as ec2-user?

Comment: yeah, 100% sure,  updated

Comment: The output seems to say the exact same thing: your private key was rejected, the server doesn't have any public key that matches it. Sorry I don't think I can help you more than that. Good luck